# Installing MAAS error postgree error

Tags: maas

I've tried to Install MAAS from Ubuntu server ISO 16 and 17, on a physical machine but both installations stops at the last steps showning the error in the image

[image]

Any advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The same happens installing off the latest (as of 2017.11.01) Ubuntu 16.04 iso.

I choose **Install Ubuntu server**, then select **PostgreSQL Database** and **OpenSSH Server** in software selection.

once this is done, on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maas
reboot
```

I think that puts you at the same place you would be if the ISO install worked.